# Limit to a function

Tags: limits

So I'm having trouble with the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x^2-x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+5}-3}}$$

Common factor doesn't work. Any hints on how to tackle it?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate the denominator? If so, you can apply L'hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

1. How about multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+5} +3$
2. Can you then factor numerator and denominator and see any factors that cancel?
3. You should be able to take it from there.

Make sense?

~A

Comment: Thanks! I did an identical exercise this morning, I can't believe how I missed the conjugate!.

Comment: Excellent! I would also suggest trying it using the definition of limits and see if you can work through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try using L'Hopital's rule

Comment: I don't know it yet

Comment: Ahh then Amzoti's answer is the way to go :)